# remove surrounding ERB tag just with vim plugin rails and surround

Tags: vim, surround, rails.vim

In vim, `yss-` can add the erb tag <% %> surrounding the current sentence.

If I want to do the opposite operation, `ds<%` doesn't work. I have to repeat these typing like: `ds%` followed by `ds<` to remove the erb tag completely.

Is there a more direct way to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697)?

Comment: Great, I now see that this is an old question, but it came up as I was trying searching - trying to remember what the plugin was called.